# Why the submit button inside the td tag don't work?

Tags: php, html, forms, button

As title say, the button "eliminaRecensioneBTN" inside td don't work. I tryed to put the button outsite the tag and it worked, but if I put that button outside the td tag it work; I need that inside.

**PHP code:**

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    if (!(isset($_SESSION['autorizzato']) && $_SESSION['autorizzato'] == true)) {
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
    $nomepagina = 'sezioni';

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'gestione');
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connessione non riuscita: ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    function prendiRecensioni($conn){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM recensioni";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<form method='POST' action='".eliminaRecensione($conn)."'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['nomevisualizzato']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['pubblicazione']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".mb_strimwidth($row['descrizione'], 0, 20, "...")."</td>";
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."' />";
                    echo "<td class='text-right'>";
                        echo "<button type='submit' name='eliminaRecensioneBTN' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Elimina</button>";
                    echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            echo "</form>";
        }
    }

    function eliminaRecensione($conn){
        if(isset($_POST['eliminaRecensioneBTN'])){
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $sql = "DELETE FROM recensioni WHERE id='$id'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
        }
    }
?>
```

I dont' know how to fix, so how can I fix it?

Comment: Could it be your line `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` returns no results? ... And even if it does in which script do you call `eliminaRecensione()`. All looks to be the same script so you never capture any requests?

Comment: Form action should be an URL or file but you are echoing a meta tag. Why's that?

Comment: Your html is invalid. Inputs should have unique names, otherwise only the last input with the same name will be captured upon submit.

Comment: I doubt very much that the `<td>` tag is the issue.

Comment: @jrswgtr but if I put the button outside the td tag it works

Comment: Your `<form>` tag will result in the following HTML: `<form method='POST' action='<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>'>` when `$_POST['eliminaRecensioneBTN']` is set. Now think for a second...., how could this ever work?

Comment: @jrswgtr I removed the meta tag, but I doesn't work anyway

Comment: Your PHP as well as your HTML is not right. Please check my answer

Comment: Your code is [open to SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/).  [Use PDO and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/6089612).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `action` attribute from the `<form>` tag so the form will `POST` to the same URL it's on.

In the top of the file, check if the form is posted and delete the post using the SQL query.

**After** that, get the results and display the forms using HTML.

Don't forget to put a `<table>` tag around your `<tr>` and `<td>` tags!

Put the `hidden` input at the bottom of the `<form>` tag, outside the `<table>`. It isn't going to be displayed anyway!

```php
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'gestione' );
if ( ! $conn ) {
    die( "Connessione non riuscita: " . mysqli_connect_error() );
}

if ( isset( $_POST['eliminaRecensioneBTN'] ) && isset( $_POST['id'] ) ) {
    $conn->query( "DELETE FROM recensioni WHERE id='$_POST['id']'" );
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">';
}

$result = $conn->query( 'SELECT * FROM recensioni' );
?>

<?php while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ): ?>
    <form method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['nomevisualizzato']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['pubblicazione']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo mb_strimwidth( $row['descrizione'], 0, 20, '...' ); ?></td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    <button type="submit" name="eliminaRecensioneBTN" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Elimina
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
    </form>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```